# Trying to get two links (which are really forms) to line up on same line on page

Tags: php, css, html

I am trying to display two text links in a foreach loop for every result. But these links will be PDO database calls to delete or update, so I need to to list them as forms that are styled to look like text. My question is how can I get these two links (as forms) to appear side to side like this: Form Approve | Form Delete ?

Currently it looks like this:

```
Form Approve (as a button)
|
Form Delete (as a button)
```

Here is the code so far:

```
<?php
echo "<hr>" . $results[text];
?>
<form action="" method="post"><button type="submit" class="formlink">Approve</button>
</form>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<form action="" method="post"><button type="submit"
class="formlink">Delete</button></form>
```

IN STYLE.CSS:

```
button.formlink {
-moz-user-select: text;
background: none;
border: none;
color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 1em;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
display:inline-block
}

button.formlink:hover span {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

As a bonus for the PHP people, I would actually prefer if I could echo these links as forms in php....

Comment: As `form` are considered as a block level element so you need to align them using `display:inline-block`.

Comment: instead of applying `display:inline-block` on button itself; use on form like this. `form{display:inline-block};` check my answer below for more explanation.

Comment: So you mean have two classes...one for form and one for button in style.css?

Comment: nope, if you check my answer I just write the two alternate lines. Use any one line to align the forms.  1. `form{display:inline-block}`
2. `div{ display:flex;}`

Comment: what's with all the downvotes? Was it not fair question? I tried both approaches with no luck. You are saying add form{display:inline-block} between the <style> tags on the actual page right?

Comment: can you post the working URL or share the rendered HTML code?

Comment: You can view the current code and how it is displays here: http://theperfecteverything.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/formstyle.jpg.  Note that there are two sets of links. The ones that display correctly are just echo php text and not forms. I would love for the form to look like that, but you can see the links in the form are stacked vertically

Comment: no need to use `div` inside the `form`. make a container `div` and inside that put the `forms`. Like this. `<div><form action="" method="post"><button type="submit" class="link"><span>Form Approve</span>  
</button></form>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<form action="" method="post"><button type="submit"
class="link"><span>Form Delete</span></button></form>
</div>`

Comment: is that helps you now?

Comment: Thanks. tried copying and pasting your suggested code with <div> surrounding everything. But links still appear one on top of the other (not lining up on same line). Maybe it can't be done with forms?

Comment: its very strange that my solution not working for you. it seems some other CSS code is messing the layout..this is the best way to align the items next to eachother using `flex` and `display:inline-block` and `float:left`. but I am wonder here in your case none of these solution working..

Answer (score 1):

Add style="display:inline-block" to both the forms.

Please refer the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/znwLd23f/)

CSS

```
form {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**This is just for the demo, avoid styling the** `element`, rather add a `class` to both the `form` and add the `display:inline-block` rule to the class

Comment: Well, I moved the styling code to style.css (see updated post above) and removed the span tags and changed class reference to formlink. However, same results, except now they are buttons and not links. I might actually be ok with buttons, but still can't get them to appear side to side as Approve | Delete

Comment: Did you care to check the posted fiddle in the answer? Where have you used the rule ``display:inline-block;``, to which ``selector``?

Answer (score 0):

As `form` element treated as a `block` level element because of this form are appear in next line, you can put them in one line using `display:inline-block`.

In addition you can use latest CSS3 property called `flex`

I am sure you are using any container like `div` which contains these forms.

so if you apply  `display:flex;` the forms will also aligned. check the `Flex` **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cafoyora/1/edit)**.

like this CSS.

```
form{display:inline-block}
div{ display:flex;} /*Assuming the forms are inside this div*/
```

Comment: If this solution solves you problem; you may accept this answer.